# Nutritious protein substance for vitamin enhanced crop?

Tags: dna, proteins, biotechnology, vitamins

I am not a bio or science major, but we have a subject, like an elective on biotechnology and we were tasked to think of a product that hasn't been invented yet. My groupmates and I thought of a vitamin enhanced crop to help fight against malnutrition. As for the crop we thought of using sweet potatoes and altering its DNA to produce a more nutritious one.

Our plan is to use agrobacterium tumefaciens, cut its plasmid and insert a foreign DNA to it. Now we are stuck with what foreign DNA can we add to it so that we will produce a more nutritious sweet potato.

Our teacher gave us a hint that whatever we will add to the organism should be a protein because the DNA only codes for protein. So if we plan to add vitamins to the sweet potato then it should be protein-based.

Sorry but I am very confused with biotech terms because I am not a bio major. But any help would be very much appreciated! thank you in advance!

Comment: Proteins are not vitamins. It's plausible that you could add proteins to synthesize a vitamin. That  said, I think plants already make all the vitamins they need. I think you need to reevaluate your objectives.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! can you give example of proteins that could synthesize a vitamin?

Comment: This question is broad. There are many vitamins and each of them has a different biosynthetic pathway. You should also make an attempt to answer before asking others. If you have done so then please add it in the question.

Comment: You might want to look into http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_rice

Comment: I'd start by looking at the nutritional facts for a sweet potato. What does it lack in? Now, look at biosynthesis pathways for your compound, and get a handle on what the precursors are, and what proteins are necessary. It could be just as easy as a Google search like "Vitamin C biosynthesis." There's also the Monsanto route ala Bt corn, but it'll take some digging through literature either way.